# Bizarre behavior in modal popup / gallery (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am encountering some strange transition behavior with the modal popup / gallery of the Work section on my website.

It works just fine in Firefox, but in Chrome when you have opened one of the portfolio links a second time - sometimes the first time - the transition doesn't occur correctly, showing an upside down image:

[image]

The image slider in the popups is built on Owl Carousel, but I don't think the problem is with that but rather something to do with the how the modal transition works. However, the problem only occurs in modals which I have used the slider on... the other popups which contain only a single image do not have the same issue.

I have spent the last TWO days trying to debug this annoying issue and it is driving me *crazy*. Nothing I have tried to fix it has worked - attempting to swap out Owl Carousel with a different carousel-based plugin didn't make any difference. I just want to get it solved so I can move onto the next thing - can someone **PLEASE** help me to solve this? :(

This is my _work.scss file:

```
#work.paddingstandard {
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}


/* ---- isotope grid---- */

#portfoliogrid .item {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

#portfoliogrid .item.width2 {
  width: 40%;

}

#portfoliogrid img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
}

/* Item rollover */

#work .item .rollover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

#work .item .rollover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 26%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 40px;
  transition: all 0.2s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s 0.6s, margin-top 0.3s 0.6s;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s 0.6s, margin-top 0.3s 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  background:rgba(196, 71, 65, 0.85);

}

#work .item.width2 .rollover:before {
  width: 25%;
  left: 38%;

}

#work .item .rollover .centerContainer {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s 0.1s;
  transform: rotateZ(-5deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0.1s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-5deg);

}

#work .item .rollover .centerContainer a {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: $white;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none !important;

  &.details {
    font-size: 0.95rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.02rem;
    color: $grey-800;
  }

}

#work .item .rollover .centerContainer .title {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  line-height: 2.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#work .item:hover .rollover:before,
#work .portfolioActive .rollover:before {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s 0.4s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s, margin-top 0.3s 0.1s;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0.4s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s, margin-top 0.3s 0.1s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);

}

#work .item:hover .centerContainer,
#work .portfolioActive .centerContainer {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s 0.6s;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);

}



/* WORK OPEN ANIMATION */

@keyframes turn {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  15% {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }

  25% {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }

  40% {
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }

  65% {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }

  90% {
    transform: rotate(405deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(405deg);
  }

}

#workLoader {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

}

#workLoader .iconloader {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

}

#workLoader .iconloader:after {
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  background-color: rgba(196, 71, 65, 0.65);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55);
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  animation: turn 4s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1) infinite;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  -webkit-animation: turn 4s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1) infinite;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);

}

#workLoader.width2 .iconloader:after {
  width: 25%;
  left: 38%;
}

#workLoader .front, #workLoader .back {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

}

#workLoader .front {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
}

#workLoader .front img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

#workLoader .back {
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, .95);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);

}

#workLoader .back #wrkclosebtn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;

}

#workLoader .back .fa-times {
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #5f5f5f

}

#workLoader .back .fa-times:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF
}

.scale100 {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(-180deg);

}

#workdetailcontainer.darkBackground {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

/* FIX IE 9/10/11 */

.IE #workLoader {
  transition: all .8s !important;
  transform: none;
}

.IE #workLoader .front, .IE #workLoader .back {
  transition: all .8s !important;
}

.IE #workLoader .back {
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(180deg) !important;
}

.IE #wrkclosebtn {
  display: none;
}

.IE .scale100 #wrkclosebtn {
  display: inline;
}

.IE .scale100 {
  transition: none !important;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) !important;
}

.IE #workLoader.scale100 .back {
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(0deg) !important;
  z-index: 10;

}

.IE #workLoader.scale100 .front {
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(-180deg) !important;
}

.IE9 #workLoader {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================

  WORK DETAILS

========================================================================== */

#workdetail {
  padding: 40px 0;

  h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-align: left;
  }

  p {
    @include safe-rem(margin-bottom, 25);
    color: $white
  }

}


#workdetail #detailImg img {
  width: 100%;
}

#workdetail .workDouble #detailImg {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}


#workdetail #details {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;

  span {
    @include safe-rem(padding-right, 8);
    color: $red-100;
  }

  li {
    @include safe-rem(margin-bottom, 12);
    color: $white;
  }

}


/* ==========================================================================

  ISOTOPE FILTERS GENERAL

========================================================================== */

.isotopeFilter {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.isotopeFilter a {
  @include safe-rem(padding, 0 25 0 25);
  font-size: 1.250rem;
}

.isotopeFilter .is-checked {
  color: $red;
}
```

This is an example of the main HTML:

```
   <div id="portfoliogrid">
        <!-- Begin item -->
        <div class="item width2 ui">
            <div class="rollover">
                <div class="centerContainer hidden-xs">
                    <div>
                        <a class="title" href="$ThemeDir/work-gallery-1.html">STARTUP BROS</a>
                        <a class="details" href="$ThemeDir/work-gallery-1.html">VIEW DETAILS</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item Image -->
            <img src="$ThemeDir/img/work/startupbros-1.jpg" alt="Portfolio" />
        </div>
```

and this is an example of the HTML inside one of the modal popups:

```
<div id="workdetail">

    <section class="container">

        <div class="workDouble">

            <div id="detailImg">

                <div id="sliderwork1" class="owl-carousel">

                    <div class="item"><img src="themes/portfolio/img/work/startupbros-large-1.jpg" alt="Startup Bros" /></div>

                    <div class="item"><img src="themes/portfolio/img/work/startupbros-large-2.jpg" alt="Startup Bros" /></div>

                    <div class="item"><img src="themes/portfolio/img/work/startupbros-large-3.jpg" alt="Startup Bros" /></div>

                    <div class="item"><img src="themes/portfolio/img/work/startupbros-large-4.jpg" alt="Startup Bros" /></div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <article>

                <h1>STARTUP BROS</h1>

                <p>Pellentesque erat velit, pretium vitae dui tempor, scelerisque posuere mi. Etiam fringilla scelerisque nulla volutpat vehicula. Donec tempus ut diam ac pharetra. Quisque quis odio convallis, imperdiet purus dignissim, tempor urna. Curabitur ut nisl nec orci scelerisque vehicula vitae eu nunc. Mauris et felis ligula. Maecenas tincidunt, augue a pulvinar laoreet, arcu nunc semper felis, lobortis gravida elit tellus non nisl.</p>

                <ul id="details">

                    <li><span>CLIENT:</span>Company Name</li>

                    <li><span>RELEASE DATE:</span>20 February 2014</li>

                    <li><span>TAGS:</span>Photography, Corporate, Flat</li>

                </ul>

                <a href="https://www.behance.net/gallery/47278647/StartupBros-UI-concepts-WIP" target="_blank>"><button class="large" href="#">LAUNCH PROJECT</button></a>

            </article>

        </div>

    </section>

</div>

<!-- End content of project details -->
```

```
<script data-scriptdetail="">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var $sliderwork = $("#sliderwork1");

        if($sliderwork.length){

            $sliderwork .owlCarousel({

                loop : true,

                animateIn: 'backSlideIn',

                animateOut: 'backSlideOut',

                autoplay: true,

                autoplayTimeout: 3000,

                margin : 20,

                nav: false,

                dots: false,

                items : 1

            });
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Also my main.js file which contains all the primary Javascript: http://www.samnorris.net/portfolio-ss/themes/portfolio/js/main.js

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to replicate your issue, however my guess is Chrome isn't resetting the state of your opened portfolio piece because you simply hide it when closing the overlay (not reverse the transition). There's too much going on here for me to pinpoint where this is, but you may have some luck with specifying an `animation-fill-mode`. This informs the browser about which state to use as a starting/endpoint. It may help you with "resetting" things. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Another strategy is to greatly simply things and start adding back in animations until you hit the issue.

And finally, for more complicated transitions it's often more beneficial to use a JS library like http://velocityjs.org/ which you can then chain together your transition/animations. You'll get more fine grained control and avoid hacking away at your CSS to get things to work.

Comment: Oh well, I'm still as confused as I was in the first place tbh... but thanks for the advice.